How does ATP store and release energy?
According to online sources, the energy in ATP is stored between the 2nd and 3rd phosphate groups of ATP and it is released when ATP is hydrolysized. However, I was under the impression that energy isn't really stored in bonds; rather, it depends on bond enthalpy and the stability of the products or reactants. Likewise, I thought breaking these bonds doesn't release energy, it absorbs it.
I basically thought that when ATP is synthesized from ADP and Pi, the bonds of the reactants are stronger and have a higher bond enthalpy than the product of the reaction, ATP. Going from high to low enthalpy causes energy to be absorbed. If this is correct, does this energy go into the phosphate bonds in ATP and is energy really stored in these bonds in the first place?
Likewise, I believed that the opposite happens when ATP is hydrolysized: low to high enthalpy due to the instability of ATP compared to the products of ADP and Pi causes energy to be released.
This may be very incorrect because I haven't taken a formal chemistry course yet, but if it is please explain. Thank you!

Sounds like you got it right.

Storing energy in bonds means the energy needed to break such bonds is smaller than energy released to create new, stronger bonds.

BTW in not impressed with your "online sources" ;)

Water?$\ce{}$$\ce{}$

This question is similar to: ATP break down and energy release?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As was mentioned above, how does water play into this? The answer above said, " Energy is always required to break bonds and always is released when bonds are formed, even with ATP, but the part that is omitted is that more molecules of water are bound and ordered after the ATP hydrolysis than before and so more ordering plus many more highly energetic hydrogen bonds formed than broken equals a large overall release of energy for the overall process." However, wouldn't more ordering decrease entropy and cause an absorption of energy instead of energy release?
